# How do I list Oracle Apps profile options in PL/SQL?

Tags: c#, oracle, configuration

I administrate several Oracle Apps environment, and currently check profile options in lots of environments by loading up forms in each environment, and manually checking each variable, which requires a lot of time.

Is there a snippet of code which will list profile options and at what level and who they are applied to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to query `APPLSYS.FND_PROFILE_OPTIONS` and `FND_PROFILE_OPTION_VALUES`. 
For a comprehensive script that you can pick up the SQL from, look here: 
http://tipsnscripts.com/?p=16

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you get more granular information when you try to track down changes by users.

```
SELECT FP.LEVEL_ID "Level ID", 
     FPO.PROFILE_OPTION_NAME "PROFILE NAME",
     FP.LEVEL_VALUE "LEVEL VALUE",
     DECODE (FP.LEVEL_ID,
             10001,
             'SITE',
             10002,
             'APPLICATION',
             10003,
             'RESPONSIBILITY',
             10004,
             'USER')
        "LEVEL",
     DECODE (FP.LEVEL_ID,
             10001,
             'SITE',
             10002,
             APPLICATION_SHORT_NAME,
             10003,
             RESPONSIBILITY_NAME,
             10004,
             FL.USER_NAME)
        LVALUE,
     FPO.USER_PROFILE_OPTION_NAME "PROFILE DESCRIPTION",
     FP.PROFILE_OPTION_VALUE "PROFILE VALUE",
     FU.USER_NAME "USER NAME",
     FU.LAST_UPDATE_DATE
FROM FND_PROFILE_OPTIONS_VL FPO,
     FND_PROFILE_OPTION_VALUES FP,
     FND_RESPONSIBILITY_TL,
     FND_APPLICATION FA,
     FND_USER FL,
     FND_USER FU
WHERE FPO.APPLICATION_ID = FP.APPLICATION_ID
     AND FPO.PROFILE_OPTION_ID = FP.PROFILE_OPTION_ID
     AND FP.LEVEL_VALUE = FL.USER_ID(+)
     AND FP.LEVEL_VALUE = RESPONSIBILITY_ID(+)
     AND FP.LEVEL_VALUE = FA.APPLICATION_ID(+)
     AND FU.USER_ID = FP.LAST_UPDATED_BY
     AND FP.PROFILE_OPTION_VALUE IS NOT NULL
     AND (UPPER (FP.Profile_Option_Value) LIKE UPPER ('%&1%')
          OR UPPER (FP.Profile_Option_Value) LIKE UPPER ('%&2%'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Armed with the knowledge of which tables to get (thanks Sten) and a bit of judicious editing, I have come up with a query which serves my needs:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(e.profile_option_name,1,30) PROFILE,
    DECODE(a.level_id,10001,'Site',10002,'Application',10003,'Responsibility',10004,'User') L,
    DECODE(a.level_id,10001,'Site',10002,c.application_short_name,10003,b.responsibility_name,10004,d.user_name) LValue,
    NVL(a.profile_option_value,'Is Null') Value,
    SUBSTR(a.last_update_date,1,25) UPDATED_DATE
FROM fnd_profile_option_values a
INNER JOIN fnd_profile_options e ON a.profile_option_id = e.profile_option_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fnd_responsibility_tl b ON a.level_value = b.responsibility_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN fnd_application c ON a.level_value = c.application_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN fnd_user d ON a.level_value = d.user_id
WHERE e.profile_option_name LIKE '%&1%'
ORDER BY profile_option_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(e.profile_option_name,1,30) PROFILE,
    DECODE(a.level_id,10001,'Site',10002,'Application',10003,'Responsibility',10004,'User') L,
    DECODE(a.level_id,10001,'Site',10002,c.application_short_name,10003,b.responsibility_name,10004,d.user_name) LValue,
    NVL(a.profile_option_value,'Is Null') Value,
    SUBSTR(a.last_update_date,1,25) UPDATED_DATE
FROM fnd_profile_option_values a
INNER JOIN fnd_profile_options e ON a.profile_option_id = e.profile_option_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN fnd_responsibility_tl b ON a.level_value = b.responsibility_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN fnd_application c ON a.level_value = c.application_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN fnd_user d ON a.level_value = d.user_id
WHERE e.profile_option_name LIKE '%&1%'
ORDER BY profile_option_name;
```